# Calling a php script at the end of a js script

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I was wondering how to call a php script from javascript, I know your meant to use AJAX but I just cant get it to work.

I have a contact me form in html, and onClick, it activates a javascript script, that validates the values entered into the different fields.

If all are valid I want it to call a php script called mail.php, that sends an email.

The html, javascript and php scripts all work, its just this little bit I'm not sure of.

Form:

```
    <form name="mail" id="mail" method="post">
        <textarea class="message" name="message" id="message">Input message to send here.</textarea>
          <div class ="type">
          <h2>Contact</h2><br /><br />
          <h3>Name</h3><br />
          <h3>Email</h3><br />
          <h3>Subject</h3><br />
          <div class="text-boxes">
             <input type="text" class="input-text" name="name" id="name"/><br /><br />
             <input type="text" class="input-text" name="email" id="email"/><br /><br />
             <input type="text" class="input-text" name="subject" id="subject"/><br /><br />
          </div>
          <div class="submit">
             <input type="image" src="images/submit.gif" alt="Submit button" onClick="validate(this.form)"/>
          </div>
     </form>
```

On submit, the form calls a js script.

Thanks.

Comment: **Derek** is probably right, please read the tutorial: [PHP Forms](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) to learn about it.

Comment: The php works fine, its calling the script I was having problems with, because the form calls javascript, and wasn't sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `submit` the form. (or use JavaScript to valid the form *then* submit it)

```
<form id="email_form">
    <input name="name">
    <input type="submit" id="submit_btn">
</form>
```

Then `mail.php` will get the information, and you can do whatever you want there.

### ADDED

To submit a `form` in JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector("#submit_btn").addEventListener("click",function(e){
    var form = document.querySelector("#email_form");  //Select the form
    form.submit();                            //Submit it (very self-explanatory)
    e.preventDefault();
},false);
```

Comment: That was sort of what I was going for, with the javascript validating it first.
How do I get it to submit after I run the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Your form tag is missing the action attribute:

```
<form name="mail" id="mail" method="post" action="mail.php">
```

Without it, the form will not submit to anywhere!

Take note that the `mail.php` should be on the same folder that your `html` file.

---

Additionally, to submit with JavaScript, after you've validated all fields, you can:

```
document.forms["mail"].submit();
```

**Note:**

If you post your javascript and PHP, a better help can be provided!